# How to parallel-process data in memory mapped file

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

As name of memory mapped file indicates, I understand that a part of a large file can be mapped to memory using class `MemoryMappedFile` in C# for fast data process. What I would like to do with the memory mapped file is to parallel-process the memory mapped. In order to do that, I have following questions

1. Is `MemoryMappedFileViewAccessor` thread-safe and Parallel.For-safe? I actually made a demo program to test the question and it seems to be working. But can't find any reference about this. If the answer is yes, I am done. Otherwise,
2. Is there any way to directly access the memory mapped with array? I know `MemoryMappedFileViewAccessor` has ReadArray method but using the method is duplication of the memory.

Comment: does your parallel processing involve modifying the file or only reading from it?

Comment: @CharlesLambert No, the data processing involves operations of accessor.Write or accessor.Read which are basically accessing memory mapped. Memory mapped file actually takes care of file operation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can reason this out.  A memory mapped file is just a chunk of memory in your program whose bytes are accessible by more than one process.  They are pretty awkward in managed code since this chunk exists at a specific address.  Which requires accessing the data using a pointer, they are taboo in managed code.  The MemoryMappedFileViewAccessor wraps that pointer, it *copies* data from managed memory to the shared memory.  Do note that this defeats the major reason for using MMFs, and why their support took so long to show up in .NET.  Be sure that you don't want to use named pipes instead.

So reasoning this out, a MMF certainly isn't thread-safe by design since this is shared memory, just like global variables are in your code.  Things go wrong the exact same way if threads read and write the same section of the shared memory.  And you have to protect against that the exact same as well, a lock to ensure only one thread can access a shared section.

Also note that you need to implement that locking between the processes that read and write the MMF.  Which tends to be painful, you have to use a named mutex that the "master" process creates and the "slave" process opens.  You cannot skimp on that locking requirement.   Notable is that you never mentioned taking care of this in your question, so Red Flag there.

Within one process, threads that don't access the same section of the MMF cannot get in each others way.  Just like two threads that access *different* variables don't require any synchronization.  As long as they hold the mutex that ensures that another process cannot write to the section.  Note that this probably means you want to use a Semaphore to protect the MMF access, a Mutex can only be acquired by one thread.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, MemoryMappedViewAccessor is derived from UnmanagedMemoryAccessor, which appears immutable, although doesn't have readonly fields - at least it doesn't modify existing fields during read/write operations, which makes it thread safe. In turn, it reads memory mapped file data from [SafeBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safebuffer.aspx) class, which contains following text in [comments header](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Runtime/InteropServices/SafeBuffer@cs/1305376/SafeBuffer@cs):

```
/* Keep the penalties for using this class small, both in terms of space 
// and time.  Having multiple threads reading from a memory mapped file
// will already require 2 additional interlocked operations.  If we add in 
// a "current position" concept, that requires additional space in memory and 
// synchronization.  Since the position in memory is often (but not always)
// something that can be stored on the stack, we can save some memory by 
// excluding it from this object.  However, avoiding the need for
// synchronization is a more significant win.  This design allows multiple
// threads to read and write memory simultaneously without locks (as long as
// you don't write to a region of memory that overlaps with what another 
// thread is accessing).
```

So my guess is that operations with memory mapped files are thread-safe, although it is strange that there is no confirmation of this in MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

1) MSDN states for both `MemoryMappedFile` and `MemoryMappedViewAccessor` that:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

2) the point of the MemoryMappedFile is not to reduce memory allocation. If you were reading the file from disk, you would have to allocate memory to store the items you read out of the file. This is also the case with the memory mapped file as well

Comment: @Thomas Memory mapped files still consume address space, of course. In fact an unnamed memory mapped file is not very different from a low-level OS memory allocation of the same granularity.